# php register script with jquery not working as it should

Tags: php, jquery

I am new to php and cannot seem to understand the problem in my code:

```
<?php
    require('mysql_connect.php');
    // If the values are posted, insert them into the database.
    if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])&& isset($_POST['phone'])){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $query = "INSERT INTO `user` (username, password, email,phone) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$email', '$phone')";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        if($result){
            $msg = "User Created Successfully.";
            }

        echo "
        <script >
        function changeIT() {
        $( '#phone,#reg' ).css('display','inline');
        }
        $(document).ready(changeIT);

        </script>";
        header('Location: http://atestat-cpi.comeze.com/index.html');
     }
?>
```

As of my understanding of php,this should execute the jquery to show the required elements and then display the index.html with the elements shown.The problem is that when the page is accesed,it displays nothing,just blank window,so I think the jQuery is not executed.Please help.

Comment: Once you type `header('Location: http://atestat-cpi.comeze.com/index.html');` you will be redirected to that uri, so your `echo` does not have effect. The JS code should be in your index file.

Answer (score 1):

`header('Location: /')` makes a redirect, so nothing will happen. You have to reorder your code and your files. I show you through an example a way to proceed.

In first instance, let's prepare your index file. I'll use ajax directly instead a typically form submit. *This is an example*:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- load jQuery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- call to your own js -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="register_user.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Instead of create a form you can do so -->
    <div id="register">
        <label><input id="user" type="text" value="" /></label>
        <label><input id="pass" type="password" value="" /></label>
        <label><input id="phone" type="phone" value="" /></label>
        <label><input id="email" type="email" value="" /></label>
        <input id="register_user" type="button" value="register!" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, let's set up your javascript file, I called it `register_user.js`:

```
// on dom ready
$(function(){
    $('#register_user').on('click', function(){

        // disable button, prevent multiple calls
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.prop('disabled', true);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'register.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                username: $('#user').val(),
                password: $('#pass').val(),
                phone: $('#phone').val(),
                email: $('#email').val()
            },
            success: function(data){
                var response = data.split('|');
                if( response[0] == '1' ){

                    // this is part of your code, it should be in your index file
                    $('#phone, #reg').css('display', 'inline');

                    // restore the button (if you want) or whatever you want to do .)
                    $this.prop('disabled', false);
                }
                else{
                    alert(response[1]);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And now let's make your php user-register script. This should be a standalone script and I called it `register.php`:

```
<?php
$responses = array(
    '-1|One or more required fields were not filled',
    '0|There was an error creating the user. Try again.',
    '1|Your user account was created successfully!'
);

if( isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['phone'], $_POST['email']) ){
    require_once 'mysql_connect.php';

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    // You MUST use mysqli, but now let's use your current code
    $query = "INSERT INTO `user` (username, password, email,phone) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$email', '$phone')";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    // If the user was created successfully, say ok.
    // The usually is to say yes or no (1 or 0) and manage the message with JS in the view.
    if( $result ) echo responses[2];
    else echo responses[1];
    exit();
}
echo responses[0];
exit();
?>
```

PS: I did not test this code, so it can have fails or things to fix. Do not remember it is just an example.

Comment: Thanks alot,will try this code,seems a bit simpler than what I currently have

Comment: Adapted your code to my needs,but it looks like the js won't catch the echo from the php,showing it on the page instead.The echo is correct,but won't activate the js part.I don't know how to post the code,because of char limit

Comment: figured it out.Reposted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30682319/jsajax-wont-catch-php-echo-it-will-display-on-page-instead

Comment: Take a look to the button. I used an input `type button` instead of `type submit`. It could be the problem. To use a submit button, just change the input type and, into js code, just after the ajax closure, type `return false` to prevent form submit and a possible reload of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this..

```
<?php
  //php code..
?>
<script>
  <!--your script-->
</script>
<?php
  //php code..
?>
```

If you want to work `jQuery` you should include the `jquery library` also.

Comment: the jquery lib is included in the html,the php file is external.and the code won't work.it loads register.php,displays blank screen and stops,instead of redirecting to modified index.html.

Comment: @user3402472 The problem is that you are not modifying your index.html. `header('Location: xxxx')` just makes a redirect.

Comment: could you please suggest how to do that?

Comment: I can't seem to be able to post my code because character excess,so I will post a link to the code files,as for js ,I am preety shure it is right.It's the ph part that i am not able to correct.It laments about " Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';' " on line 47 https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzYVCaMl1OmoSUVJLU51NXBpUGc/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzYVCaMl1OmoQWhmLVpNUENTckU/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Once you type `header('Location: http://atestat-cpi.comeze.com/index.html');` you will be redirected to that uri, so your echo does not have effect.  Also it looks like you are not including JQuery, you can include it using CDN https://jquery.com/download/#using-jquery-with-a-cdn. Also in this code you have major problems with SQL injection. You should escape the user input with `mysql_real_escape_string(input)` method.